# Code lens disappeared in VS Code after 3 year. How can i get it back?

Tags: visual-studio-code, c#, unity3d

Didn't change anything started up pc 2 days ago. Opened vs code and for some reason, I'm not getting code lense anymore. I tried a lot from turning it first on and of, restarting pc, Updating vs code, and Changing editor in unity back and forth. resetting all settings, Reinstalling vs code. Restarting pc again, Opening different projects folder, deleting vs file in the project and recreating it again.

But nothing helped and I'm very dependent on code lens for unity development. I tried looking up a lot but nobody seems to have this with vs code only in visual studio (Year). So I can't find anything that can help.

It's strange that after 3 years of always having it work out of nowhere it stopped.

Also compared the setting with my laptop and they are the same. But code lens does work on my laptop and not on me

I really would appreciate any help I have tried so much but nothing seems to work.

[How it is now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAeP7.png)
[How it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izrkk.png)

[Setting 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaItQ.png)
[Setting 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5bRn.png)

It's solved by doing this stackoverflow.com/a/72404936/224734

Thanks to
frankhermes

Comment: Have you tried to restart VS Code?

Comment: Multiple times sadly still it wont work

Comment: This worked!!!! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72404123/omnisharp-error-about-dotnet-version-unity/72404936#72404936

Answer (score 0):

The poster has indicated that the solution was found in the post
[Omnisharp error about dotnet version - Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72404123/omnisharp-error-about-dotnet-version-unity/72404936#72404936),
reproduced here:

> If you're using C# extension 1.25.0 they announced a change in the
> extension's details page:
>
> > .NET Framework builds of OmniSharp no longer ship with Mono or the
> > MSBuild tooling (See announcement omnisharp-roslyn#2339). To ensure
> > that the C# extension remains usable out of the box for .NET SDK
> > projects, we have changed the default value of omnisharp.useModernNet
> > to true.
> >
> > If you still need Unity or .NET Framework support, you can set
> > `omnisharp.useModernNet` to `false` in your VS Code settings and restart
> > OmniSharp.
>
> Changing that `omnisharp.useModernNet` setting to `false` worked for
> me.